# ASP POST back to itself, then to HTTPS. Vulnerabilities?

Tags: http, forms, asp-classic, https

I am struggling with securing webforms from shenanigans (previously, our "contact us" webform would submit the form's contents to an ASP that generated the e-mails, leaving it vulnerable to attack from a page outside of our website since the URL was in the form's action). In an attempt to combat the spam, I altered the classic ASP page to POST back to itself before posting to another ASP that handled the e-mail. I used code I found on [15 Seconds site](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/990128.htm) to prevent multiple submits, and changed all of the posted variables to Session Variables before re-posting it to an HTTPS page. I include a hidden input field with the Session ID in it, and on the page on the HTTPS side, verify all of the fields have data in them and verify the submitted Session ID matches the current Session ID.

I'd **like** to think this is pretty secure (short of putting it all into HTTPS), but I'm not sure. Does the initial ASP posting back to itself before posting to the HTTPS page leave a hole that could be exploited? Did I over-engineer one part while leaving another wide open?

Comment: Let me clarify: the spam we were getting was probably because the page being posted to contained the code to generate the e-mails, and the form field contained all the information a spammer would need to create his own form to submit to our confirmation/e-mail page. What I did is change the field names when the form is posted back to itself, and then post those to the e-mail/confirmation page, along with a Session ID.

Comment: My question is, when the page is posting back to itself (before posting to the e-mail page), what sort of hole is there that could be exploited? Am I right in assuming the data is being posted in the clear, and could be compromised?

Answer (score 0):

How about using captcha? 
There are several easy to implement scripts for generating captcha images, which should remove your spam problem easily.

For example: http://www.tipstricks.org/

Captcha removes both kind of problems you mentioned - it removes computer generated spam and blocks multiple submits of the same data, since the captcha image value changes each time it is refreshed.

Comment: We've considered that; my question is, assuming the captcha keeps the user on the form until they get it the captcha right, how does the confirmation page (the page being posted to) "know" the user got the captcha right?